# Should I use PostgreSql, MySql, Oracle or SqlServer for storing documents / binary files?

Tags: sql, database, binary

Should I use PostgreSql, MySql, Oracle or SqlServer for storing documents / binary files ?
Are there any performance benefits of using one or the other? Are there any advantages/disadvantages?

Documents stored will be mainly excel files, image files, pdf's and images.

Answer (score 5):

Some would say that you shouldn't store the binary files in the database, and that you should just store the path, and keep the files in the standard file system.  Of course which path you take depends a lot on what you are doing with the files, without knowing more about your requirements it's hard to say.