# PHP MySQL Storage of Word Document

Tags: php, mysql, database

How can I make it so that a user can upload and then store their word document in a database so that they can download it as a word document later?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php and http://php.net/pdo.

Comment: possible duplicate of this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285857/when-is-using-mysql-blob-recommended

Answer (score 1):

Storing files in a regular RDBM is generally considered to be bad practice. I would recommend storing the files on the file system and storing the path to the file in some kind of `VARCHAR` or `TEXT` field in the database. If you're desperate to store the file in the database look at storing it in a `BINARY` blob or base64 encoding it.

Comment: So how would I upload to document and then store it on the file system

Answer (score 0):

The Word document should not be stored IN the database. A good practice would be to only store a link to a file within the public scope of your website.