# Saving base64 image to server

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-s3

[image]

How should I save a base64 image to server? I don't want to lose the resolution when next time user retrieve it. Just save the data object and it will be fine?

Answer (score 0):

You might get some arguments about storing images in the database, rather than a in separate folder and storing a link in the database. But if you do want to store the image in the database then you can use a BLOB field. There are some examples in the following links : 
http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/php_mysql_example__image_gallery_(blob_storage).xml
[Insert Blobs in MySql databases with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052655/insert-blobs-in-mysql-databases-with-php)
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql-blob/

Comment: where does the image goes physically? storing media file in db is old, it's pricey and unable to scale.

Comment: The physical location is dependant on storage engine (& MySQL version). There is some more info on the pros & cons of using BLOBS here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285857/when-is-using-mysql-blob-recommended & MySQL docs here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html